# LibGDX Error reading file: images/skin.json. I get this error in google play console but not in my ide no

Tags: android, json, libgdx

I get this error, about not being able to load textures, only in the google play console, but not in the IDE I'm using (Intelij). But why?

This is my json:

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
    background: {
      down: shade,
      up: shade
    }
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
    default-horizontal: {
      background: slider-background,
      knob: slider-knob-1,
      knobBefore: slider-knobBefore,
      knobAfter: slider-knobAfter
    },
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
    default-horizontal: {
      background: slider-background,
      knob: slider-background,
      knobBefore: slider-knobBefore,
      knobAfter: slider-knobAfter
    },
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image: {
    background: {
      drawable: shade
    },
    speaker-high: {
      drawable: speaker-high
    },
    speaker-medium: {
      drawable: speaker-medium
    },
    speaker-low: {
      drawable: speaker-low
    },
    line: {
      drawable: line
    },
    googlePlayGamesIcon-Off: {
      drawable: googlePlayGamesIcon-Off
    },
    googlePlayGamesIcon-On: {
      drawable: googlePlayGamesIcon-On
    },
  },
}
```

This is how I load the skin:

```
skinMenu = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_MENU_UI));
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception Process: com.pixelvalue.connection, PID: 9821
a1.d0: Error reading file: images/menuTexture.json
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load (Skin.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init> (Skin.java)
  at com.pixelvalue.connection.screens.game.Game.<init> (Game.java)
  at com.pixelvalue.connection.screens.MainScreen.show (MainScreen.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen (Game.java)
  at com.pixelvalue.connection.MyGdxGame.create (MyGdxGame.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged (AndroidGraphics.java)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun (GLSurfaceView.java:1557)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run (GLSurfaceView.java:1272)
Caused by a1.d0: Error reading file: images/menuTexture.json
  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson (Json.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load (Skin.java)
Caused by a1.d0:
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read (Skin.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read (Skin.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue (Json.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue (Skin.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson (Json.java)
Caused by b1.e: Class not found: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle
  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.forName (ClassReflection.java)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read (Skin.java)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle
  at java.lang.Class.classForName
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:454)
  at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:379)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.forName (ClassReflection.java)
```

Path to files:

connection\assets\images\menuTexture.atlas

connection\assets\images\menuTexture.json

connection\assets\images\menuTexture.png

I would like to make it work and know why it is not working? Thanks for every answer :).

Comment: You probably have an issue with your proguard configuration. Have you ever edited it since creating your project?

Comment: I have never edited it but thank you for the tip. I will try to look for the error there.